# Compose function with Enumerator

Tags: scala, scalaz, loops

Is it possible to compose an arbitrary function with an Enumerator or EnumeratorM, so that each individual item of data being pushed into the iteratee is first preprocessed by applying the function?

Comment: It's my own fault for not reading the tags before giving a Play 2.0 answer, but you might want to be more explicit about the iteratee library you're using (and the version, which I'm assuming is 6, since you mention `EnumeratorM`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Scalaz 6 at least, no - not if the function has a return type that is different from (and not a subtype of) its argument type, because `EnumeratorM`'s type doesn't allow it to change the input type of the iteratee.

However, it is possible to "pre-compose" arbitrary functions with an *iteratee*, so I think this is the way to go. Could also maybe use an enumeratee, but this abstraction is not provided in Scalaz 6.